# issue with aws waf visibility config with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

I'm having some trouble deploying the below terraform code. It keeps erroring during apply the following error:

> │ Error: Insufficient visibility_config blocks │  │   on ignore.tf
> line 66, in resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "this": │   66:   rule { │  │
> At least 1 "visibility_config" blocks are required. ╵ ╷ │ Error:
> Unsupported block type │  │   on ignore.tf line 78, in resource
> "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "this": │   78:     visibility_config { │  │
> Blocks of type "visibility_config" are not expected here. ╵

I have defined it per the instructions and checked the patterns in the Terraform docs by comparing them with other configs. One suggestion was to add the "override action" block inside the rule to count or none but this does not seem to make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
//ip-set
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "this" {
  name               = "${var.name}-ip-whitelist"
  description        = var.description
  scope              = var.scope
  ip_address_version = var.ip-add-ver
  addresses          = var.ip-address
  tags               = var.tags
}


//web acl
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "this" {
  name        = "${var.name}-web-acl"
  description = "${var.name}-web-acl"
  scope       = var.scope
  tags        = var.tags

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }
  
  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "friendly-rule-metric-name"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }

  rule {
    name     = "ip-set-rule"
    priority = 1

    override_action {
      count {}
    }

    statement {
      ip_set_reference_statement {
        arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.this.arn
      }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "friendly-rule-metric-name"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
    }
  }
}

//acl association
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "default_web_acl_association" {
  resource_arn = var.target_resource
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.this.arn
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl). The very first example on that page shows what you are missing. You need to have a `visibility_config` block at the top level of the resource, not inside any `rule` blocks.

Comment: I have amended the OP with your suggestion but did try this previously and it failed with the same error. In the doc, there is another example where the visibility_config is nested inside the rule but nevertheless, i seem to be hitting the same issue.

Comment: You moved the visibility `visibility_config` from inside the rule, to outside the rule. You should have left the one in the rule, and added a new one at the top level. You need BOTH.

Comment: Thanks for the above. I have added this and tried again but seem to be hitting 2 errors now. The second of which says "Blocks of type "visibility_config" are not expected here." I have updated the OP with the the info.

Comment: Please pay attention to the code. You placed the block inside the `statement` block. It should be at the same level as the `statement` block, not inside of it.

Comment: thanks for your help and please accept my apologies for the confusion.